# Identity Aware Proxy Page not showing my domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

I've setup my GCP App Engine app to use the Identity Aware Proxy (IAP) to limit which users can see/use my app. I followed [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart#oauth-configure).

However, when I navigate to my page the login screen says: "Sign in
to continue to iap.googleapis.com".

How do I get it to say "Sign in to continue to MYDOMAIN.com"?

I've configured the "OAuth consent screen" properly w/ my domain and contact info, but it doesn't seem to be getting applied.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi OP, can you confirm which `User Type` did you use in the OAuth consent screen? Also, is your [app verified](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en)?

Comment: Hi, it's External user type. Verification says "Verification not required".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [article](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615?hl=en), verification is required when a project is configured for a user type of **External** and a publishing status of **In production**, and would want to display the App or Logo name.

> Submitting for verification may not be required, based on the current configuration of your OAuth consent screen. Users may not see all of your app's information, including its name and logo, until your project has completed verification.

Additionally, see this list of [OAuth verification criteria](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615?hl=en#verification-status):

- You want to display an icon or display name for your project on the OAuth consent screen.
- Your project's OAuth clients request authorization of any sensitive or restricted scopes.
- The number of authorized domains for your project exceeds the domain count limit.
- There are changes to your project's OAuth consent screen configuration after a previous published, verified configuration.